# React.js: Passing nested props into React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code of the form

```
props = { user: {userattr1: 1, userattr2: 2}};
var element = React.createElement(MyReactClass, props);
```

i.e., where props is a *nested object*. When I try to compile the above code I get the error:

Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

I've been looking online and it seems that nested objects are perfectly permissible as props. How can I resolve my error?

Edit: `MyReactClass` looks something like this:

```
var MyReactClass = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    <div>{this.props.user}</div>
  }
})
```

Comment: You don't get an error but a warning

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle. I think your problem is elsewhere, not the props. How is MyReactClass defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the problem, you are having is related to a nested object as props. Here it is an example:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.user.name}</div>;
    }
});

var props = { user: {name: "World"}};
React.render(React.createElement(Hello, props), document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/urjmndzk

More likely, your problem is related to how you are setting the keys of the children components. However, it is hard to tell without seeing the entire code.

This is a link to the `creeateFragment` function, it may help you. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html

Comment: It turns out that the problem was in the fact that I was trying to use an object in the HTML markup, under the assumption that React would use its JSON representation.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using JSX, you can also pass a nested object as a prop by building the object like this:

```
<HelloWorldClass user={{name:'Kyle'}} />
```

#### Syntax Example in Stack Snipets

```js
// function component syntax
function HelloWorldFunc(props) {
  return (
    <div>Hello, {props.user.name} </div>
  );
}
// class component syntax
class HelloWorldClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        Hello, {this.props.user.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// createElement syntax
const helloCreate = React.createElement(HelloWorldFunc, {user:{name:'Kyle'}});
// JSX syntax
const helloJSX = <HelloWorldClass user={{name:'Kyle'}} />

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {helloCreate}
    {helloJSX}
  </div>
,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```